# Create SDK with implementation off puckettunnel provider (nsextensionprincipalclass)

Tags: ios, networkextension

I'm trying to create an app with VPN and packet tunnel provider everything work perfectly when the PacketTunnelProvider implementation happens inside the app 
but I developing an SDK and I want to use plist nsextensionprincipalclass key to tell the iOS system which class will be the entry point to PacketTunnelProvider

I try to create a class that implements NEPacketTunnelProvider in the SDK, and the main app to the use pucketnsextensionprincipalclass name of the class 
also, try to create target inside the SDK  and use nsextensionprincipalclass in the main app not work also

what is I'm doing wrong?